# Robust way to avoid run-on words when using text_content() on html elements

Tags: python, string, text, lxml

We are parsing web pages.  One goal is to find all the words and their frequencies.  We have been using lxml

```
from lxml import html

my_string = open(some_file_path).read()

tree = html.fromstring(my_string)

text_no_markup = tree.text_content()
```

Well we would see things like this a_wordconcatenated_to_another

when we were expecting a_word concatenated_to_another

Looking more closely it seems that this happens when a_word is followed by a close tag of some sort and then some more html markup and then without any spaces or line breaks concatenated_to_another would be enclosed in some markup.

The only way I could figure out to fix this was by

```
my_modified_string = open(some_file_path).read().replace('>','> ')
```

So I replace all gt signs with a gt sign and a space.

Is there a more robust way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`itertext()`](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html#itertext)

```
>>> my_string = '''
... <div>
...     <b>hello</b>world
... </div>
... '''
>>>
>>> root = html.fromstring(my_string)
>>> print root.text_content()

    helloworld

>>> for text in root.itertext():
...     text = text.strip()
...     if text: # to skip empty(or space-only) string
...         print text
...
hello
world
>>> print ' '.join(root.itertext())

     hello world
```

Comment: I don't have lxml installed, but I wonder how does this handle `<h1><font size=120% color=Red><u>W</u></font>ebsite</h1>`?

Comment: @StevenRumbalski, `' '.join(html.fromstring('<h1><font size=120% color=Red><u>W</u></font>ebsite</h1>').itertext())` yields `'W ebsite'`,  while `html.fromstring('<h1><font size=120% color=Red><u>W</u></font>ebsite</h1>').text_content()` yields `'Website'`.

Comment: So basically `get_text()` acts like `''.join(root.itertext())` and your method is to change the join character from an empty string to a space.  It's a good method, but the OP should be aware that sometimes undesirable spaces will be returned.

Comment: Yes I gathered as much but w ebsite link is better then websitelink